# разбить строку по словам в scala

Tags: scala

Подскажите пожалуйста есть входная строка типа

`val string_1 = "head.headmaster.master"`
или типа
`val string_1 = "head.headmaster"`

Мне необходимо всегда вытаскивать первое слово в отдельную переменную
`val record = topic.string_1("\\.")(0)`
В другую переменную мне необходимо записывать остаток от строки, причем это могут быть либо два элемента тогда с разделителем "_", либо один элемент. Причем так, чтобы это все не сломалось в том случае, т.е. не зависимо от количества слов в переменной string_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для разбивания строки на части можно использовать метод `split`, установив максимальный порог - 2 остатка разделения.

```
val string_1 = "head.headmaster.master"

val arr = string_1.split("\\.", 2)
// Array("head", "headmaster.master")
```

Вторая часть задачи сформулированна менее чётко. Реализовать запись в переменные можно вот так:

```
arr match {
  case Array(record) => // когда на входе только одно слово
  case Array(record_1, record_2) => // когда на входе 2 и больше слов
}
```